# Counting NA values by ID?

Tags: r, aggregate, na

I'm learning R from scratch right now and am trying to count the number of NA's within a given table, aggregated by the ID of the file it came from.  I then want to output that information in a new data frame, showing just the ID and the sum of the NA lines contained within.  I've looked at some similar questions, but they all seem to deal with very short datasets, whereas mine is comparably long (10k + lines) so I can't call out each individual line to aggregate.

Ideally, if I start with a data table called "Data" with a total of four columns, and one column called "ID", I would like to output a data frame that is simply:

```
[ID] [NA_Count]

1    500

2    352

3    100
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Try `library(dplyr); library(tidyr);gather(data, Var, Val, -ID) %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(CountNA = sum(is.na(Val)))`

Comment: Are you trying to read in a decent number of files, and then count the total number of missing values from each file? If so, how are the files structured? Are there multiple variables per file?

Comment: Please take a look at the following link to put together a minimal reproducible example. [minimum example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @lmo - yes, I have a total of 300 .csv's that I am using to make my full data frame.  Each of them have an identical column structure - Date, Field 1, Field 2, ID (which is really just one value identifying the file - 1 for 001.csv, 2 for 002.csv, etc).  I want to be able to display, by ID, total number of rows containing NA's.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work, although I am assuming that Date is always there and Field 1 and Field 2 are numeric:

```
# get file names and initialize a vector for the counts
fileNames <- list.files(<filePath>)
missRowsVec <- integer(length(fileNames))

# loop through files, get number of 
for(filePos in 1:length(fileNames)) {
  # read in files **fill in <filePath>**
  temp <- read.csv(paste0(<filePath>, fileNames[filePos]), as.is=TRUE)

  # count the number of rows with missing values,
  # ** fill in <fieldName#> with strings of variable names **
  missRowsVec[filePos]  <- sum(apply(temp[, c(<field1Name>, <field2Name>)], 
                                 function(i) anyNA(i)))
} # end loop

# build data frame
myDataFrame <- data.frame("fileNames"=fileNames, "missCount"=missRowsVec)
```

This may be a bit dense, but it should work more or less. Try small portions of it, like just some inner function, to see how stuff works.